# Transact-SQL Equivalent in golang mongodb aggregate

Tags: mongodb, go, aggregation-framework

I have a SQL statement that I am trying to recreate in golang using a mongodb database.  The statement that I am trying to recreate is the following:

```
select date,
       sum(case when field1 = "true" then 1 else 0) trueField1,
       sum(case when field1 = "false" then 1 else 0) falseField1,
       sum(case when field2 = "true" then 1 else 0) trueField2,
       sum(case when field2 = "false" then 1 else 0) falseField2
from myTable
group by date
```

I need to total out a few combinations on a given date and dump them out, but I am unsure how to accomplish it via golang / mongodb.

**Edited:**  here is the starting point that i have per the last request. as can be seen from o1 it shows what I'm going after on the first sum / count. i would also like to sum another field isDelivered and sum them on the same date returning the count for the same day. can i get some direction on how i would accomplish this task?

```
    o1 := bson.M{
        "$match" : bson.M {
            "retailer" : clientId,
            "isComplete" : true,
            "pkgStatus.finalized" : true,
            },
    }

    o2 := bson.M {
        "$project" : bson.M {
            "_id" : 1,
            "createdAt" : 1,
        },
    }

    o3 := bson.M{
        "$group": bson.M{
            "_id" : bson.M{ "$dayOfYear": "$createdAt" },
            "total" : bson.M{ "$sum" : 1},
            "first" : bson.M{ "$min" : "$createdAt" },
        },
    }

    o4 := bson.M {
        "$sort" : bson.M { "_id" : 1 },
    }

    totalMessages := []bson.M{msgsStarted, o2, o3, o4}

    operations := []bson.M{o1, o2, o3, o4}

    pipe := cMessages.Pipe(operations)

    results := []bson.M{}
    err := pipe.All(&results)

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Error: %s\n", err)
        return
    }

    for _, resultRec := range results {
        myDate := fmt.Sprintf("%s", resultRec["first"])
        fmt.Printf("%s, %d\n", myDate[0:10], resultRec["total"])
    }
```

**EDIT2**

Schema definition

```
messages {
  "_id" : {
    "$oid" : bson.ObjectId
  },
  "isComplete" : bool,
  "status" : {
    "cancelled" : bool,
    "finalized" : bool,
    "delivered" : bool
  },
  "createdDate" : {
    "$date" : ISODate
  }
```

I'm attempting to take the $cond statements that you provided guidance on before and nest it with an $and command, so that I can do the following:

```
sum(case when isComplete = true and status.finalized = true then 1 else 0)
```

I've been playing with the following:

```
tf1c := bson.M{"$cond": []interface{}{bson.M{"$eq": []interface{}{"iscomplete", true}}, 1, 0}}
```

but unsure of the syntax exactly.  I believe it should follow something like this, but not sure how to translate it exactly (the below is from another stackoverflow thread)

```
"$cond": [{
    "$and": [{
      "$eq": ["isComplete", true]
    }, {
      "$eq": ["pkgStatus.finalized", true]
    }]
}, 1, 0]
```

Thanks again for the guidance!

**Unwrapping the Map**

How do you unwrap the map?

```
map[_id:map[date:2014-12-25 retailer:ObjectIdHex("548a9de8a4ea9d690f6df8e4")]]
```

to retrieve the values. I have tried the following but it returns null.

```
fmt.Printf("%s\n", resultRec["_id.date"])
```

Comment: Have you even tried to read [MongoDB aggregation framework documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/) before asking the question? And by the way, NoSQL doesn't mean we don't need information about documents structure.

Comment: Yes, I did read the documentation but am still experiencing issues hence the reason I posted the question.  This is supposed to be a place we are to receive help when we run into an issue.

Comment: I see no issue here. The issue is when you are trying to do something and result of your tries doesn't work. The issue is when you don't understand how something works and this thing is not documented. In your case, all I see is the request to do some job for you for free without ANY efforts from your side to solve it by yourself. Except writing this post, of course. Show us queries/code you have tried and we will see what is wrong with it.

Comment: Roman, everything I have seen via documentation and examples / posts are very basic queries resulting in only one sum or value returned for a date value. I'm just asking for additional guidance or push in the right direction to build the correct solution myself. I'm not even sure where to start other  than summing for one field.  If thats what you are asking for, then I can post it as well but it is going to lead to the same question of where should I go from here or how do I expand the operation pipe to include another sum on another field. Does that make sense?

Comment: Hi CRob! Welcome to your first question! In order to help you we just need more information. Can you add the go code to your question with which you are experiencing problems? Currently we only have the sql statement which is only half of what we need. That will help us pinpoint the problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. That's better but there is still no information about your DB schema to understand which data types you are using. Here is the Mongo's equivalent of SQL query in case if all fields are in string format:

```
package main

import (
    "gopkg.in/mgo.v2"
    "gopkg.in/mgo.v2/bson"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    session, err := mgo.Dial("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/db")

    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer session.Close()
    session.SetMode(mgo.Monotonic, true)

    db := session.DB("db")
    c := db.C("MyTable")

    tf1c := bson.M{"$cond": []interface{}{bson.M{"$eq": []interface{}{"$field1", "true"}}, 1, 0}}
    ff1c := bson.M{"$cond": []interface{}{bson.M{"$eq": []interface{}{"$field1", "false"}}, 1, 0}}
    tf2c := bson.M{"$cond": []interface{}{bson.M{"$eq": []interface{}{"$field2", "true"}}, 1, 0}}
    ff2c := bson.M{"$cond": []interface{}{bson.M{"$eq": []interface{}{"$field2", "false"}}, 1, 0}}

    pipe := c.Pipe(
        []bson.M{
            bson.M{
                "$group": bson.M{
                    "_id": "$date",
                    "trueField1": bson.M{"$sum": tf1c},
                    "falseField1": bson.M{"$sum": ff1c},
                    "trueField2": bson.M{"$sum": tf2c},
                    "falseField2": bson.M{"$sum": ff2c},
                },
            },
            bson.M{
                "$sort": bson.M{"_id": -1},
            },
        },
    )
    result := []bson.M{}
    err = pipe.All(&result)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("%+v", result)
}
```

**Update**:

```
pipe := c.Pipe(
        []bson.M{
            bson.M{
                "$project": bson.M{
                    "year": bson.M{"$year": "$createdDate"},
                    "month": bson.M{"$month": "$createdDate"},
                    "day": bson.M{"$dayOfMonth": "$createdDate"},
                    "val": bson.M{"$cond":[]interface{}{
                        bson.M{
                            "$and": []interface{}{
                                bson.M{"$eq": []interface{}{"$isComplete", true}},
                                bson.M{"$eq": []interface{}{"$status.finalized", true}},
                            },
                        },
                        1,
                        0,
                    }},
                },
            },
            bson.M{
                "$group": bson.M{
                    "_id": bson.M{
                        "$concat": []interface{}{
                            bson.M{"$substr": []interface{}{"$year", 0, -1}},
                            "-",
                            bson.M{"$substr": []interface{}{"$month", 0, -1}},
                            "-",
                            bson.M{"$substr": []interface{}{"$day", 0, -1}},
                        },
                    },
                    "cnt": bson.M{"$sum": "$val"},
                },
            },
            bson.M{
                "$sort": bson.M{"_id": -1},
            },
        },
    )
```

Comment: This has been very helpful, and I would like to up vote your answers but cannot due to my reputation being too low.  Otherwise, it would definitely be done.

Comment: Roman, I'm looking online for assistance in expanding the $cond to include an $and.  I don't see too many examples out there, can you point me in the right direction of where to look?  I read through the documentation you pointed out above. I also found another stackoverflow thread, but it isn't formatted for bson.  Should I start a new thread to show what I have tried, or expand on this one?

Comment: @CRob I think would be easier to keep it here. And don't forget to link SQL version of the query as it makes easier to understand what final result you are expecting.

Comment: I'll post schema as well since I neglected that part before.

Comment: I think I have provided everything you asked for but if I missed something please let me know.

Comment: @CRob added new query.

Comment: Thank you so much! You have been so helpful on this learning curve. I have another question for you on how you unwrap the map...see above noted section..

Comment: @CRob simple `resultRec["_id"]["date"]`

Comment: I tried that and receive back the following error: invalid operation: resultRec["_id"]["date"] (type interface {} does not support indexing)

Comment: @CRob `resultRec["_id"].(bson.M)["date"]`

Comment: once again you have rocked!   +1